# Filter records with specific values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access 2013 VBA SQL to filter Access table.  Need to pick items which have warehouse 20 and 21 only.

```
Item    Warehouse

Item1   25
Item1   21
Item1   22
Item1   22

Item2   20
Item2   21
Item2   21
Item2   21
Item2   21

Item3   20
Item3   22
Item3   23
Item3   25
Item3   25
Item3   25

Item4   20
Item4   20
Item4   20
Item4   21
Item4   21

Item5   20
Item5   20
Item5   20
Item5   20
Item5   20
```

Result is Item2 and Item4 on the above example.  Thank you.

Comment: You really can't come up with this straightforward query using `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 3):

If you want 20 and 21 *as well as* others:

```
select item
from t
where warehouse in (20, 21)
group by item
having min(warehouse) = 20 and max(warehouse) = 21;
```

If you want 20 and 21 *but no others*:

```
select item
from t
group by item
having min(warehouse) = 20 and max(warehouse) = 21;
```

If you want 20 or 21 *but no others*:

```
select item
from t
group by item
having sum(iif(warehouse = 20, 1, 0)) > 0 and
       sum(iif(warehouse = 21, 1, 0)) > 0 and
       sum(iif(warehouse in (20, 21), 0, 1) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple inner join on the table to itself using Item as the join and filtering the first table by Item 20 and the second table by Item 21

Using DISTINCT will remove the duplicates

`SELECT DISTINCT WH20Items.Item
FROM Table1 AS WH20Items INNER JOIN Table1 AS WH21Items ON WH20Items.Item = WH21Items.Item
WHERE (((WH20Items.Warehouse)=20) AND ((WH21Items.Warehouse)=21));`